# How to calculate bincount in mxnet

Tags: mxnet

I am trying to implement my customer layer for neural network using mxnet. I was wondering if there is a function in mxnet similar to [np.bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). If not, is there a way I can calculate it without having to convert my `mx.ndarray` to `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MXNet doesn't have such functionality. You can implement it by writing a loop like this:

```
bins = []
for i in range(max_value):
    bins.append(nd.sum(my_array == i))
bins = nd.concat(bins)
```

Keep in mind that if you use numpy, not only you're switching from GPU context to CPU and slowing down the computation, you also cannot do backprop on the computation.